# SQL trigger, reference to ID of deleted record

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use the following code in order to delete all records from table where ID is the same as just deleted record from test:

```
CREATE TRIGGER usun ON test
FOR delete
as
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table WHERE id_test = deleted.id_test;
END
```

This error was displayed by SQL Server 2012:

> The multi-part identifier "deleted.id_test" could not be bound.

I can not find any solution for this issue. I have tried to write "old" instead of "deleted" and nothing happens.

Comment: A simpler way to accomplish this would be to define a foreign key on `table.id_test` which references `usun.id_test`, and state ON DELETE CASCADE when creating the foreign key constraint. If you do this the database will handle the cleanup for you, saving you from having to write this sort of trigger. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deleted` is a table, not a "record".  Try this:

```
DELETE FROM table
    WHERE id_test in (select id_test from deleted.id_test);
```

Comment: Thanks. It will delete all rows from "table" where ID is the same as in deleted rows from "test"?

Comment: @user3162968 . . . Yes, that is what it should do.